# Multiple Columns in Oracle TableView

Tags: database, oracle, javafx, tableview

my code is working to 90% I think.
The Output is right, but not all columns are shown in the tableview.
I don't know where the problem is.

The fx:id is right, the code too, I believe.

Here's a picture of the openend program. I will give you also my output an my controller an table-code. The launching code isn't important.

Picture:
http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3791/aitj4rff_png.htm

Output:

```
*** Loaded Oracle-Driver ***
*** Connected with Database ***
Film: Hugo          Gesehen: JA
Film: FAST and FURIOS 6         Gesehen: JA
Film: Emil          Gesehen: NEIN
Film: DAS_BOOT          Gesehen: JA
*** Database data saved to Observable List named 'data'
*** Table Items setted ***
```

table_controller:

```
package controller;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import oracle.jdbc.*;
import model.filmtable_data;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class table_controller implements Initializable {
    private ObservableList<filmtable_data> filmData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @FXML
    private TableView<filmtable_data> FilmTable;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<filmtable_data, String> Filmtitel_Col;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<filmtable_data, Integer> ID_Col;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<filmtable_data, String> Gesehen_Col;



    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // Observable List

        ID_Col.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<filmtable_data, Integer>("rID"));
        Filmtitel_Col.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<filmtable_data, String>("rFilmtitel"));
        Gesehen_Col.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<filmtable_data, String>("rGesehen"));
            try {
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                System.out.println("*** Loaded Oracle-Driver ***");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                System.out.println("Driver-Loading failed.");
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:lukas/1234@10.140.79.39:1521:OTTO");
            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("SELECT FILMTITEL, GESEHEN FROM LUKA1");
            String filmtitel = "empty";
            String gesehen = "empty";
            int zaehler = 1;
            System.out.println("*** Connected with Database ***");
            while (resultset.next()) {
                filmtitel = resultset.getString("FILMTITEL");
                gesehen = resultset.getString("GESEHEN");
                System.out.println("Film: " + filmtitel + "\t\t\tGesehen: " + gesehen);
                filmtable_data entry = new filmtable_data(zaehler, filmtitel, gesehen);
                filmData.add(entry);
                zaehler++;
                }
            System.out.println("*** Database data saved to Observable List named 'data'");
            FilmTable.setItems(filmData);
            System.out.println("*** Table Items setted ***");
            statement.close();
        }   catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Login fehlgeschlagen.");
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

filmtable_data:

```
package model;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class filmtable_data {

    private final SimpleIntegerProperty rID;
    private final SimpleStringProperty rFilmtitel;
    private final SimpleStringProperty rGesehen;

    public filmtable_data (Integer sID, String sFilmtitel, String sGesehen) {
        this.rID = new SimpleIntegerProperty(sID);
        this.rFilmtitel = new SimpleStringProperty(sFilmtitel);
        this.rGesehen = new SimpleStringProperty(sGesehen);
    }

    public Integer getRID() {
        return rID.get();
    }

    public void setRID(int set) {
        rID.set(set);
    }

    public String getRFilmtitel() {
        return rFilmtitel.get();
    }

    public void setRFilmtitel(String set) {
        rFilmtitel.set(set);
    }

    public String setRGesehen() {
        return rGesehen.get();
    }

    public void setRGesehen(String set) {
        rGesehen.set(set);
    }
}
```

the fx-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="366.0" prefWidth="268.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.table_controller">
   <children>
      <TableView fx:id="FilmTable" prefHeight="366.0" prefWidth="425.0">
        <columns>
            <TableColumn fx:id="ID_Col" minWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="43.0" text="ID" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="Filmtitel_Col" prefWidth="137.0" text="Filmtitel" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="Gesehen_Col" prefWidth="137.0" text="Gesehen" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your POJO class, and there is not getter:

This is wrong:

```
public String setRGesehen() {
    return rGesehen.get();
}
```

It should be:

```
public String getRGesehen() {
    return rGesehen.get();
}
```

Notice you should add also the property methods, like:

```
public StringProperty rGesehenProperty() {
    return rGesehen;
}
```

Even with the wrong getter, as the `PropertyValueFactory` looks first for the property, it would have worked.

Comment: Works! Thank you.. It's so bad to see, that it's a mistake at one letter -.- :D

Comment: Some IDEs let you generate this properties for you, avoiding these silly typos. In NetBeans, for instance, just right-click, select Insert Code... and then select Add Java FX property...

Comment: Ok, I think I will use this next time, very much thanks.

Comment: Just fyi: The same (generating JavaFX getters/setters) goes for Eclipse with efxclipse addon.

Comment: If you define the property accessors (e.g. `rGesehenProperty()`) as @JoséPereda recommends, you can (in Java 8) use a lambda expression in place of the `PropertyValueFactory`: `gesehenCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().rGesehenProperty());`. Using this approach, if you have any errors with the method naming, they will be caught by the compiler, instead of leaving you with the harder task of figuring out the runtime issues. Also, I recommend you follow [Java capitalization conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)